# How to skip the inaccessible folders with python's os.listdir?

Tags: python, directory

I'm working with python and javascript and I'm having a problem in a specific part of my program. I need to show the user/client the contents of a specific directory. I do that using python's os.listdir. This function is giving me all the contents of the directory, even inaccessible folders (which I don't want to show the user/client).

I'll you give an example. While exploring directory C:\Users\MyUser, I get this by os.listdir:

```
In [18]: os.listdir('C:\Users\MyUser')

Out[18]: ['.eclipse',  '.gimp-2.6',  '.hdfview2.7',  '.matplotlib',  '.pylint.d',  '.recently-used.xbel',  '.xy',  'AppData',  'Application Data',  'Aptana Rubles',  'Contacts',  'Cookies',  'Defini\xe7\xf5es locais',  'Desktop',  'Documents',  'Downloads',  'Dropbox',  'Favorites',  'InstallAnywhere',  'Links',  'Menu Iniciar',  'Modelos',  'Music',  'My Documents',  'NetHood',  'OpenSignals Files',  'Os meus documentos',  'Pictures',  'PrintHood',  'Recent',  'Saved Games',  'SciTE.session',  'Searches',  'SendTo',  'Thumbs.db', 'Tracing',  'Videos',  'workspace',  '_ipython']
```

I can't access some of the given folders. For example: Application Data, Cookies, Menu Iniciar (portuguese for Start Menu), Modelos, Os meus Documentos (portuguese for My Documents), NetHood, PrintHood and SendTo. If I try to access them with python, I get this error:

```
WindowsError             Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Users\Plux\<ipython console> in <module>()

WindowsError: [Error 5] Denied Access: 'C:\\Users\\Plux\\Cookies/*.*'
```

So, my question is, how can I detect the inaccessible folders and skip them to only show the user the folders he can explore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for el in os.listdir('C:\Users\MyUser'):
    try:
        (check if you can open, if so, you can show this folder)
    except WindowsError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for myFile in myList():
    if not os.access(myFile, os.R_OK):
        myList.pop(myList.index(myFile))
```

List should include paths only. Else, you need to modify the loop depending on the attributes.

Comment: That was really the solution I was hoping to find. However, the result from os.access is True for all folders even if they're not accessible...

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 10.04 and probably most Linux distributions. Try `os.W_OK` which is write permissions; if that does not work either, you need to create a try-except loop with `file()` and `os.listdir()` with `IOError` and `OSError` exceptions. It will actually way slower than that. Basically you will want to open the files and listdir the directories and if you catch any errors, pop the from array.

Comment: Ok, it's a problem with Windows probably. I will use the try-except loop, that works even if it's a bit slower... Thank you!